# Optimizing PostgreSQL for transient data

Tags: postgresql, optimization, database-tuning

I have several tables with 100-300 columns of integer types each, that hold highly volatile data. The datasets are keyed by one or two primary keys, and when refresh occurs, the whole dataset is deleted and new data is inserted in one transaction. Dataset size is usually a few hundred rows, but can be up to several thousand rows in extreme cases. Refresh occurs once per second, and dataset updates for different keys are usually disjointed, so dropping and recreating the table is not feasible.

How do I tune Postgres to handle such load? I can use the latest and greatest version if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on how many different data sets there are, one option would be to partition the tables per-dataset.

When a dataset is updated, `BEGIN` a new transaction, `TRUNCATE` the table, `COPY` the new data into it, and `COMMIT`. PostgreSQL has an optimisation where `COPY`ing into a table that's been `TRUNCATE`d *in the same transaction* does much less I/O if you're using `wal_level = minimal` (the default).

If you cannot partition and truncate (say, if you're dealing with tens or hundreds of thousands of data sets, where there'd just be too many tables) you'll instead want to crank autovacuum up to run as much as it can, make sure you have good indexes on anything you delete based on, and be prepared for somewhat ordinary performance.

If you don't need crash safety - you don't mind your tables being *empty* after a system crash - you can also create your tables as `UNLOGGED`, which will save you a huge amount of I/O cost.

If you don't mind having to restore the whole setup from a backup after a system crash you can go a step further and also set`fsync=off`, which basically says to PostgreSQL "don't bother with crash safety, I have good backups and I don't care if my data is permanently and totally unrecoverable after a crash, and I'm happy to re-`initdb` before I can use my database again".

I wrote some more about this in a similar thread on Stack Overflow about [optimising PostgreSQL for fast testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407442/optimise-postgresql-for-fast-testing); that mentions host OS tuning, separating WAL onto a different disk if you're not using `unlogged` tables, checkpointer adjustments, etc.

There's also some info in the Pg docs for [fast data loading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html) and [non-durable settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/non-durability.html).

Comment: Thanks for the partition tip, I never thought about using them in this case. As for unlogged tables - do you mean that they end up empty by default after system crash? It doesn't make any difference, I'm just curious.

Comment: @AlexTokarev That's right; after PostgreSQL shuts down uncleanly (postmaster or a backend segfaults, system power-cycles suddenly, backend is `SIGKILL`ed, etc) any `UNLOGGED` tables may be `TRUNCATE`d, so they're empty on start-up. They aren't truncated after a clean shutdown and restart, but you shouldn't rely on them being durable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't need data safety for the tables in question, the data in them is transient and is refreshed from the source every second. Turning fsync off is not an option however, as there are other, more traditional tables in the same schema that do need to be safe and recoverable. Having the `UNLOGGED` option per table is just great.

Comment: I'm looking at the partitioning doc and it looks like it could be an (almost) perfect solution to the problem. One question though: if I'm going to have a parent table for schema and child tables to hold the data, I'm going to query the data from the parent table, right? If a child table for that range exists, the query will return it, if not, it will return an empty dataset. In that case I can even drop and re-create child tables for each fresh data batch. Given the circumstances, what will be more effective, `TRUNCATE` or `DROP/CREATE TABLE` sequence?

Comment: @AlexTokarev I'd recommend that you `TRUNCATE`, personally. DDL churn has its own costs. Since you're making changes with such a high frequently it'll be very important to make sure that you turn up autovacuum's aggressiveness on `pg_catalog.pg_class` and other system tables that might bloat under that workload.

Comment: @AlexTokarev Just keep in mind that partitioning in PostgreSQL is suitable for at most hundreds of tables, not thousands. `constraint_exclusion` isn't super-efficient or super-smart, alas, and there's been little recent progress on smarter native partitioning code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I don't expect the number of partition tables to exceed 10-20 under the usual load, probably not more than 200 even under extreme load.